# How to create a HTML element and set something in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code which works well:

```
var el = "<span class='notification_numb'>" + notif_num + "</span>";
$("#header .header_point").prepend(el);
```

Now I want to make that element another way. Here is my new code:

```
var el = $('<span />').addClass('notification_numb').html(notif_num);
$("#header .header_point").prepend(el);
```

But it doesn't work, actually that `span` will not be created. any idea what's wrong?

Comment: i dont think a self closing span tag is valid

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/tf38ehxw/

Comment: @charlietfl Odd ..!

Comment: Any errors in console...or other changes you made ?

Comment: @charlietfl well nope .. there is no error in the console and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3CzJ.png) is my real code. It would work if I use the pure html instead of making that `span` this way `$('<span />')`.

Comment: @charlietfl I mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVLg8.png) works well.

Comment: So simply switching out the string for the jQuery object versions of `var el=` works with one and not the other? Strange indeed. Might try with `$('<span>')` without space but doubt that affects anything

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @fuzz jQuery 1.8.2

Answer (score 0):

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.setAttribute('class', 'notification_numb');
span.textContent = notif_num;
$("#header .header_point").prepend(span);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.